# Persistent game where you program your own bot(s)

Tags: multiplayer, mmo, rts, bot

I'm looking for an online game with a persistent world where you are allowed to code (and add) your own 'players' (it can be in any language / script).

A sort of RTS but for bots.

Does that even exist?

Comment: I don't know if this is going to be useful at all, but just in case. RealTimeBattle is a programming game in which you program robots that fight each other.  http://realtimebattle.sourceforge.net/

Comment: How is this game dev related?

Comment: @Tetrad : 'Programming a bot for a game' seemed quite game programming related to me.

Comment: @Dan : thanks I'll check that one out (even if it isn't in a persistent world).

Comment: @Valmond "programming a game" and "a game that involves programming" are somewhat different topics, but I'm not going to push the issue.

Comment: (There was a bit of a mix up with the migration of this question to Gaming.SE, they don't want game-recommendation questions.  Apologies to all involved.)

Comment: @Valmond I deleted the accepted answer because it contained a dead link (and was a link only). You may consider accepting another answer if you feel like it. (Or if you find the new home of GR1D, we may be able to update the link and undelete the answer.)

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is. It's called Robocode, and you basically program your own bot in Java, and fight with other people. You can battle against other AI bots, or play multiplayer over the Internet.

Here's the link to their homepage: http://robocode.sourceforge.net/.

Comment: I was about to say something like 'I have tried RoboCode a long time ago but it isn't persistent'. Thanks though & +1

Answer (score 3):

Since recently Heroes of Newerth has the ability to program bots: https://plus.google.com/u/0/112989499300264805049/posts/idAYrvc9Awn

Answer (score 1):

There is also the Ai Sandbox, which is by the creators of AiGameDev (http://aigamedev.com/)
Here is the link: http://aisandbox.com/

It isn't actually released yet though, but I for one am quite excited about it :)

Comment: Nice! +1 (but still no persistence)

Answer (score 1):

Carnage Heart on the Playstation 1 was a similar example: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carnage_Heart

Not online nor in a persistent world, but it did have an interesting flowchart-based programming model and was quite impressive for it's time.

Comment: Was like programming in Befunge! Great game.